# Remove elements with JQuery from fluid-container

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, typescript, aurelia

The basis of my project is Aurelia and Typescript. I don't know if this is important for my question, therefore I simply mention it.

Question:
I have a fluid-container with three `divs` in it. In two of these three `divs` I have `ul` elements which I want to remove.

I already have this:

```
 public async attached() {
    $('ul').remove();
 }
```

This works fine for the first `div` but unfortunately it does not remove the `ul` elements from second `div`.

How can I achieve this? I thought of probably looping over all elements or something like this.

Comment: Do these elements share a common class at all? Easier that iterating over the divs. If they share a common class you can just do '$(".class").remove()'

Comment: The code, as presented, will remove *all* `ul` elements.  If it's not doing it for all of them, then you have not provided all of the code.  Please provide more information.

Comment: Have a read of [mcve], specifically the *complete* part.

Comment: "Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the *shortest code necessary to **reproduce it in the question itself**.*"

Comment: Unfortunately we use an internal framework to create the frontend and I want to remove the element from an frameworks element. Therefore it is not possible to share all the code. I thought this is probably an easy issue to solve. However, I will contact the guys behind the framework and hopefully get my answer. Sorry for bothering you with this.

Comment: Maybe the other divs don't exist at the time the function above is called? Because if it does the code you have provided should remove all ul elements.

Comment: While not answering your question, what about a simple `if.bind="showULElements"` in the template HTML and a `boolean showULElements = false;` in your view model class instead of trying with jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

from the looks of it you just don't want those elements at all.

So why not remove them from template?
Or as one of the comments suggested put them behind `if.bind`?

Although It is so possible to mix JQuery with Aurelia.
you are on a slippery slope path to maddnes.

If you need any more assistance with this, provide a minimal repro by forking this gist.run https://gist.run/?id=8ae06845f2bdf4d533b072c00da82614